# What's the proper use of php.ini's session.save_path?

Tags: php, iis, session, session-variables

I'm running PHP on Windows/IIS.

My session variables don't seem to be preserved from page-to-page.

This code…

```
//echos out the session variables in a nice format for inspection
echo "<p><pre>";
print_r($_SESSION);
echo "</pre></p>";
```

…outputs blank values, like this…

```
    Array  
    (  
        [s_firstvar] =>  
        [s_var2] =>  
        [s_third] =>  
        [s_numberfour] =>  
        [s_youget] =>  
        [s_thepoint] =>  
        [] =>  
    )
```

I found suggestions on a forum…

> I had a similar problem recently (Win2000, IIS), and it turned out that PHP
>   did not have write-access to whatever directory that the session data was
>   stored in. You may want to look into this.

and

> have you set session.save_path?

What's the proper use of php.ini's session.save_path?  And, is that my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops.  I found that I was not using the correct syntax when assigning values:

Does not work:

```
$_SESSION['$s_firstvar'] = 3;
```

Does work:

```
$_SESSION['s_firstvar'] = 3;
```

Comment: just to be nit picky, you should get in the habit of quoting your variables:

$_SESSION['s_firstvar'] = 3;

(for example)

Comment: indeed, not quoting them creates a constant and some overhead

Comment: And ++ on the engie avatar! ;-)

Comment: Edit: quoted variables per Owen's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

can you post a bit more of your session code? some basics:

- did you start your session? ([`session_start()`](http://php.net/session_start) )
- did you check whether your save path has proper permissions (not mentioned in OP)
- session.save_path is really just the directory sessions will be saved into. if you are on a shared service, it may be better to set it to a different directory than the default temporary directory (as your sessions would be intermingled with other app's sessions as well, and could potentially lead to a greater chance of session collision)
- if you are altering session configurations (like `save_path`, these must be set previous to calling `session_start()`.